# Error in operator << overloading - no operator found

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

I have a class Graph with constructor and overloaded `operator <<`, `graph.h`:

```
class Graph
{
    private:
        vector<int> setOfVertices;
    public:
        Graph(ifstream &);      //konstruktor ze souboru
        friend ofstream & operator<<(ofstream&, const Graph &);
};
```

the definition of constructor(not important for minimal example) and operator << are in separated file `graph.cpp`:

```
ofstream & operator<<(ofstream& outputStream, const Graph & graphToPrint)
{
    //not important for minimal example
    return outputStream;
}
```

When I try to call `operator <<` in `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "graph.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream myFile ("example.txt");
    Graph * G = new Graph(myFile);
    cout << *G;
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error

```
error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Graph' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

I didn't manage to locate the mistake in the code by myself, I will be thankful for every piece of advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::cout` is a global object of type `std::ostream` not `std::ofstream`. `std::ofstream` is a derivative of `std::ostream`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout

So, modify your friend function (operator) to

```
friend ostream & operator<<(ostream&, const Graph &);
```